# Set hostname in Spring MockMvc

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

Im writing an integration test using Spring MockMvc in SpringBoot and im trying to set the hostname, the default one is `localhost`, I would like it to be a valid domain name like `localhost.com`.

I prefer a way which uses minimal code so if its possible to achieve using yml file its awesome.

Answer (score 3):

When using `MockHttpServletRequestBuilder` to build the request , you can use `with` to define a [`RequestPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/RequestPostProcessor.html) which further configure the `MockHttpServletRequest` :

```java
  mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get("/foo")
                .with(req -> {
                    req.setServerName("localhost.com");
                    return req;
                }))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Comment: I was hoping for something general so I wont have to define it for each request

Comment: You can run it as a springboot test with following annotation and specify the hostname in properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it as a spring-boot test with the following annotation and specify the hostname in properties.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {
        "HOSTNAME=mockhost",
})
public class IntegrationTest {

//test
}
```